# Need to execute task after setState finish

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to execute a task, after setState() method complete its whole job. I will describe my problem at below with some code.

I have a login screen and it has a widgets as below:

```
                      ...
                        child: TextField(
                            errorText: getErrorStringOfEmail(),
                            ...
                      ),
                      ...
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () => onClickLoginButton(),
                            ...
                          ),
```

"getErrorStringOfEmail" method is as below: (This method is called when the Textfield is updated by calling "setState()".)

```
String getErrorStringOfEmail( 
  if(loginEmailTextEditingController.text.toString() == "a") {
    isValidLogin = false;
    return 'Wrong password or email';
  }

  isValidLogin = true;
  return null;
}
```

"onClickLoginButton" is as below:

```
void onClickLoginButton() {
  setState(() {
     //in here a boolean is changed to update Textfield.
  });

  if (isValidLogin) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement (
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeWidget()),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, "isValidLogin" boolean is assigned when Textfield widget is updated. However, getErrorStringOfEmail method is called after onClickLoginButton. I need to execute the following part,

```
if (isValidLogin) {
  Navigator.pushReplacement (
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeWidget()),
  );
}
```

after getErrorStringOfEmail method is called. To achieve this, i need to call this part after setState update widgets.
How can i do this?